# Is there any memory leak with the QAudioOutput code?

Tags: c++, qt, qthread

I am playing an audio stream in a QThread like this:

```
// Setup
QAudioFormat format;
format.setFrequency(44100);
format.setChannels(2);
format.setSampleSize(16);
format.setCodec("audio/pcm");
format.setByteOrder(QAudioFormat::LittleEndian);
format.setSampleType(QAudioFormat::SignedInt);
QAudioDeviceInfo info(QAudioDeviceInfo::defaultOutputDevice());
format = info.nearestFormat(format);
this->m_AudioOutput = new QAudioOutput(format, this);
DECLARE_ALIGNED(16,uint8_t,audio_buffer)[(AVCODEC_MAX_AUDIO_FRAME_SIZE * 3) / 2];

// Playback
QIODevice *iodevice = this->m_AudioOutput->start();
for(;;) {
    // Routine that fetches audio data from network
    // data_size is length of the buffer
    fetch_packet(&audio_buffer, data_size);

    qint64 dataRemaining = data_size;
    const char *b2 = (const char *)audio_buffer;
    while (dataRemaining) {
    qint64 bytesWritten = iodevice->write((const char *)b2, dataRemaining);
        dataRemaining -= bytesWritten;
        b2 = b2 + bytesWritten ;
    }

    msleep(10);
}
```

The audio plays just fine but the app's memory consumption seems to increase over time (around 2MB per minute). I was wondering if I have done something wrong. I suppose `QAudioOutput` should be responsible for deleting the `QIODevice`'s buffer after it has been read and used for playback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think so, the docs says:

Starting to play an audio stream is simply a matter of calling start() with a QIODevice.          **QAudioOutput will then fetch the data it needs from the io device.**

It it just reading data. The QIODevice should manage the buffer. To be sure, you can check the size of your buffer using QIODevice::size() and see if it is growing.

Comment: Good idea. `QIODevice::size()` is indeed not growing. This probably means it's not `QAudioOutput` that's leaking